# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-studio

I'm trying to build an app, that pastes an input from a previous activity(works with no problem) and then shows me some things from a database(when ButtonGet is pressed). The problem is that when I try to Run the project, I get 
`Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached`. What is wrong with my code?

```
 package br.exemplozxingintegration;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.ClipData;
 import android.content.ClipboardManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
 import com.android.volley.Response;
 import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;



 public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {



     private EditText  pastetext;
     private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
     private ClipData myClip;
     private Button btn;
     private EditText textView1;
     private Button buttonGet;
     private TextView textViewResult;

     private ProgressDialog loading;


           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
               myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
               pastetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPaste);
               btn.performClick();
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

               textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
               textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

               buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);

           }



           @SuppressLint("NewApi")
           public void paste(View view) {
               ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
               ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
               String text = item.getText().toString();
               pastetext.setText(text);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Pasted",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           }


     private void getData() {
         String id = textView1.getText().toString().trim();
         if (id.equals("")) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;
         }
         loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

         String url = Config.DATA_URL+textView1.getText().toString().trim();

         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(String response) {
                 loading.dismiss();
                 showJSON(response);
             }
         },
                 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 });

         RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
         requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
     }

     private void showJSON(String response){
         String name="";
         String image = "";
         try {
             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
             JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
             JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
             name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
             image = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_IMAGE);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nImagine :\t"+ image);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         getData();
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you are ever seeing a crash, be sure to post the stack trace in logcat when stating your question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In your onCreate, you're calling super.onCreate() twice, and also setContentView() twice.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do.

Comment: Its probably the super call.  Calling setContentView twice is pointless in a single function, but is totally legal overall.

Comment: After removing the super.onCreate, I get this AppCompat does not support the current theme features. Although I have the theme instaled

Comment: @user3026270 now it sounds like you have a completely unrelated problem which could now be its own question.

Comment: @user3026270 if you found this answer to be helpful, please accept it as the correct answer and follow up with different questions in another question.

Comment: Thanks, my code had the super.onCreate method defined at multiple instances, and your solution solved mine

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you first initialize textView1, and perform the button click, at that point you are just resetting any previous settings by calling onCreate() again, and before perfomClick methods hits getData() method, inside here also tries to access the text from textView1 but you called onCreate after that and set the view from scratch. That is why you cannot get it work, delete the duplicate code

Comment: Now I get, java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Please attach logcat message and if possible DB file.
This could be the possible problem, You might be **reassign the already assigned db object** while inserting in the table.

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h4Ix0cwarGglggKK1HPZ_1syDO6Jk2hy01SW_Zwp7wg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I took out the duplicates, and now I get , java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: is it your final code of activity from where you call the DB class. If it is you haven't initialize your db yet please first initialize it. If possible please paste  your erroneous onCreate method of Second activity as well.

Comment: I init the DB in a different class. And what do u mean by "paste your erroneous onCreate method of Second activity as well".

Comment: I saw your logcat error message it says error on line 58 of second activity.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers here helped - and the Log message makes no sense - I recommend you to File->Invalidate cahce 
then run the app again and hopefully this time the log will show the correct stack trace.