# My app keeps on crashing and I am not able to see what the problem is

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code. Please check.. When I execute it the app crashes. So app was fine before, but I added validation to the form and since then as soon as the app run it crashes. I have used https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-form-validation-tutorial/ for adding awsomeform and so I have also made some changes to the strings.xml file. Please check this once too. It was fine before and I could access the file pretty easily.

This is the error I get on Android studio when I try to run the app and the app installs, launches and then crashes.

This is my mainactivity code. I believe something is going on with the implements part and the code i.e. import.com.google.common.collect.range is also unused

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.net.sip.SipSession;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.DexterError;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequestErrorListener;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;


import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.List;



import android.util.Patterns;


import android.widget.EditText;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.ValidationStyle;
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public Button btn;
    public ImageView imageview;
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts";
    public int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;
    public EditText r_name_fill, r_email_fill, r_edit_phone, r_cardetails, r_pass_fill;
    public RadioButton r_male, r_female;
    public Button r_submit;
    public AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestMultiplePermissions();

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing awesomevalidation object
        /*
         * The library provides 3 types of validation
         * BASIC
         * COLORATION
         * UNDERLABEL
         * */
        awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);

        //initializing view objects
        r_name_fill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r_name_fill);
        r_email_fill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r_email_fill);
        r_edit_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r_edit_phone);
        r_cardetails = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r_cardetails);
        r_pass_fill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r_pass_fill);

        r_male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r_male);
        r_female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r_female);
        r_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.r_submit);
        //adding validation to edittexts
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.r_name_fill, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.nameerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.r_email_fill, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.emailerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.r_pass_fill, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.passworderror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.r_edit_phone, "^[2-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$", R.string.mobileerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.r_name_fill, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.carerror);
        r_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View V) {
        if (V== r_submit) {
            submitForm();
        }
        showPictureDialog();
    }
    public void submitForm() {
        //first validate the form then move ahead
        //if this becomes true that means validation is successfull
        if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Validation Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //process the data further
        }
    }



    public void showPictureDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera"};
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    public void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void requestMultiplePermissions() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                            //openSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="383dp"
        android:layout_height="563dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r_name_fill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="John Doe"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.362"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.003" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.11" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r_email_fill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="email@techmahindra.com"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.092" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone No."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.191" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r_edit_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="+91-XXXXXX"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.905"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.174" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_gender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.256" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r_male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
        android:text="Male"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r_female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.315" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_car"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Car Details"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.059"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.375" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r_cardetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Car Details"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.905"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.385" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_dl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Driving Licence"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.071"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="223dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Select or Capture Image"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="86dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.003"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.844" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r_pass_fill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.905"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.867" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.432"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.969" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: refer to post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384888/java-lang-illegalstateexception-already-attached

Comment: In your `onCreate` you are calling `super.onCreate()` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` 2 times unser on creat lifecycle , delete one of them and it should fix your problem.